# How to get and import data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4 ( Like Products, Categories , Customers )

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, product, migration, data-migration

I have 2 store
1st one is in Magento 1.9 and Second one is in Magento 2.
So now i want to Migrate my data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2 and the data which i want to migrate is ( Like Products, Categories , Customers e.t.c).

**How to do that ant specific idea like i don't want to convert my site from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.
I just want data from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.**

Any help is appriciated.
Thanks

Comment: using migration tool you can migrate specifi data in magento 2

Answer (score 1):

In the command line for Magento 2, you need to install the Migration Tool.

To Find out your version of Magento 2

```
php <magento_root>/bin/magento --version
```

To install Migration Tool (change version number on the end to match yours)

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.4.1
```

Once you have ran this, you then need to run these:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade;
php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
php bin/magento indexer:reindex;
php bin/magento cache:clean;
php bin/magento cache:flush;
```

More information on installing and configuring the tool can be found on the Magento website.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-install.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-configure.html